# The parameter in the LINQ Where became null, which doesn't make sense to me. Why did it happen?

Tags: c#, linq

I've been writing C# and LINQ queries for a long time. I want to go through a temporary List, looking for matching values on 1 field (named Model). The spec says that if there's a matching Model, then it is not to be added to the list. So, I'm removing duplicate Models and only putting in unique ones into the list, which gets returned. Here's the function I've written to do this:

```cs
private List<InstrumentModel> EnsureInstrumentModelListUnique(List<InstrumentModel> instrumentModels)
{
    var tmpList = new List<InstrumentModel>();

    if (instrumentModels == null || instrumentModels.Count <= 1)
    {
        //nothing to see here folks, move on
        return instrumentModels;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < instrumentModels.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            tmpList.Add(instrumentModels[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            //get current model
            string model = instrumentModels[i].Model;

            //check to see if model is somewhere in the list
            var rec = tmpList.Where(t => t.Model == model).FirstOrDefault();

            //if it isn't there, put it in
            if (rec == null)
            {
                tmpList.Add(rec);
            }
        }
    }

    return tmpList;
}
```

It goes with the `for` loop 3 times, before it crashes. It crashes on the `t.Model` in `tmpList.Where(t => t.Model == model).FirstOrDefault()` claiming that `t` is null.

I don't understand how `t` is null on the third iteration through the loop. The table from which `instrumentModels` comes from has 5 records in it. All the records have something in the Model column.

Here's the definition of InstrumentModel, with only the relevant columns included for brevity's sake:

```cs
[Table("app.InstrumentModel")]
[DebuggerDisplay("ID == {ID}, Model == {Model}, Inactive == {Inactive}")]
public partial class InstrumentModel
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public InstrumentModel()
    {
        Instruments = new HashSet<Instrument>();
        PersonnelCertifications = new HashSet<PersonnelCertification>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

I'm working with WPF, .NET Framework 4.5.2, VS 2019

Comment: `if (rec == null) { tmpList.Add(rec); }` is commented *"if it isn't there, put it in"*. That's not what that does.

Comment: I would say that comments like that are actually harmful because they can prevent you from reading what you *actually* wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @madreflection pointed out, the issue is here:

```
//check to see if model is somewhere in the list
var rec = tmpList.Where(t => t.Model == model).FirstOrDefault();

//if it isn't there, put it in
if (rec == null)
{
    tmpList.Add(rec);
}
```

In this case you are inserting `rec` when you should be inserting `model`, I believe.

The code is simpler with `Any`. If you do it this way, there is no null variable to get confused about.

```
bool found = tmpList.Any(t => t.Model == model);

if (!found)
{
    tmpList.Add(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, John Wu and madreflection. I see my mistake now. I was too close to it so I didn't see it. Needed other pairs of eyes to tell me about it. It's obvious now. Also, thank you about informing me about the `Any` phrase. I presume that's analogous to a SQL `EXISTS`.